# GUI form inheritance JAVA

Tags: java, forms, swing, user-interface

Yo,I am designing an UI in Java and I ran in some trouble. Lets say we have a GUI form for a JPanel having 4 buttons,a JLabel and second panel inside it. All users are supposed to see the 4 buttons and the label,but each one sees a different Jpanel(inside one). If this was just code it would be a simple inheritance thing,but I cant seem to find any options to inherit from another panel in [JFormDesigner](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/274-jformdesigner). Can I make a Form inheriting from another Form and just change the Jpanel I want or should i just hardcode it?

Answer (score 0):

You could have the parent panel extends JPanel as below.

```
class OuterPanel extends JPanel {
   JPanel innerPanel;  //update it to show different view
   Button[] buttons;
   Labels [] lables;
}
```

Here's a panel created using NetBeans GUI.

```
public class NewJPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    public NewJPanel() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() { 
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        //and layout
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;  //inner panel,
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Yeah,thats the code option though. The question was mainly in Forms. Can I inherit a Form from another Form and change the innerPanel?

Comment: I am not familiar with JFormDesigner.  But in NetBeans, when you create a panel, it extends javax.swing.JPanel.  This is because every panel you create in the GUI builder is a custom panel.  Anything you add to the panel are store in the custom panel similar to the code I show above.